# Using other environments from Postman

Tags: postman

We have our workflow split into multiple projects, each dealing with different concerns (Central server is for **anything** authentication-related, API server for anything new-gen related, and each other project corresponds to a its own app).

This makes our process of hitting an app API as follows:

1. From Central Server local environment, post authentication
2. Set app
3. From the app environment for the end user, set to environment
4. Hit the API of the app of end user's choice

This makes for tests that are difficult to write, in that we'd have to do steps 1 through 3, and with two different environments.

Is there a way to access the variables from one environment (e.g. Central Server Local) from another, in the test script?

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are scoped to their own environment - up from that you could set a global variable in the test script and still access it when you change environments:

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables

Collection variables are also above environment variables but cannot be set programmatically, only through the collection settings.